# How To Assign Value To Session Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Work on Asp.Net C# VS08
I would like to assign a value to Session using javascript.
Is it possible?

example: Session["Id"] = document.getElementById("id").value;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session is a server-side concept; Javascript has no conception of it.

You can make an AJAX service that sets a session value.

However, you should probably use a cookie instead.
You can set cookies in Javascript using [this library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/), among others.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to do that directly with JavaScript on the client-side.

Sessions are handled on the server-side. In general your browser would simply store a cookie which uniquely identifies a session stored on your server. When you change the value of a session variable, you are storing this on the server, and the browser cookie would be unaffected.

You could however use JavaScript to send an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to your ASP.NET application, which in turn changes the session variable on the server-side. Since this involves a round-trip to the server, you would have to wait for the response, to confirm that the operation succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to a session variable like this isn't possible in JavaScript. Best you can do is write data to a cookie.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Otherwise if you want to communicate to the server use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Session is server side object. A couple of ways to do that would be to send cookies from JavaScript and use them on the server side to assign a value to a session variable, or to make an AJAX call and set the values on the backend.