# Get,set session value in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, session

I want to set session variable using javascript/jquery in my apsx page.
Afterwards,I want to use that session variable in other page using jquery.
Can anyone help me for this?

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: See this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114581/how-to-assign-value-to-session-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two cases here ,

1) If you want to set the value of Session in client side on the page load it self you can use the hidden field to pass on the client side .

2) If you want to set the value on the client side without going to back to post back , you can opt for the AJAX method

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set directly with javascript you need server side code for it. you can make an ajax call and pass parameter and set session there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the session variable value in hidden field when page is initially loaded like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HDSessionValue" runat="server" Value'<%#Session["CustomerID"]'/>
```

Now you can easily get the value from jquery or javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var SessionValue=$('#HDSessionValue').val();
alert(SessionValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the value of `session` variable to `JS` variable but to assign a value to `session` variable you need something like `ajax` working on server side